# Как узнать информацию о файле в архиве, зная путь? SevenZipSharp

Tags: c#, 7z

Можно как-то получить данные файла в архиве (индекс, размер и т.д.), не перебирая все файлы?

Как например в DotNetZip:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("1.zip");
long size = zip["dir\\file.txt"].UncompressedSize;
```

Answer (score 2):

А вы уверены, что `ZipFile` их внутри не перебирает? Похоже, что SevenZipSharp не поддерживает подобную индексацию, но ничто не мешает вам поручить перебор методу [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Linq;
...
var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor("test.7z");
var size = extractor.ArchiveFileData.First(f => f.FileName == "dir\\file.txt").Size;
```

При желании, можете написать метод расширения:

```
public static long GetFileSize(this SevenZipExtractor extractor, string fileName)
{
    return (long)extractor.ArchiveFileData.First(f => f.FileName == fileName).Size;
}
```

Comment: Что за метод First? У меня такого нет

Comment: @a1bT это метод расширения для коллекций, возвращает первый элемент, удовлетворяющий условию. Подключите System.Linq. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx